# Can't get console-stamp to log to custom output file

Tags: node.js

This extension https://github.com/starak/node-console-stamp specifically the "Custom Console" isn't outputting to the specified file.

I've done exactly as the page says to implement the "Custom Console" option but it doesn't work. I've tried several things to try and debug this but im not getting anywhere. I have documented a lot here on this page https://github.com/starak/node-console-stamp/issues/33

```
const fs = require('fs');
require('console-stamp')(console, {
    colors: {
        stamp: 'yellow',
        label: 'white',
        metadata: 'green'
    }
});

const output = fs.createWriteStream(`./logs/stdout.${getLogFileDate()}.log`);
const errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream(`./logs/stderr.${getLogFileDate()}.log`);
const logger = new console.Console(output, errorOutput);

require('console-stamp')(logger, {
    stdout: output,
    stderr: errorOutput
});

console.log( ' TEST LOG ' );
```

I expect the output file to contain the log but the output file remains empty. The output file does get created, just doesn't seem to want to write to it.

I have tested just doing

```
const output = fs.createWriteStream(`./logs/stdout.${getLogFileDate()}.log`);

output.write('foop\n');
output.write('bop\n');
return;
```

and that worked

Comment: have you requested `fs`? `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: yes sir ... i should probably update my code snippet to show that sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for using console-stamp :)

The first part of you code is for patching the global console, and should not be used like that when you want a custom console.

The next part is correct, but you are not using your custom console, `logger` anywhere.

Try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const output = fs.createWriteStream(`./logs/stdout.${getLogFileDate()}.log`);
const errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream(`./logs/stderr.${getLogFileDate()}.log`);
const logger = new console.Console(output, errorOutput);
const console_stamp = require('console-stamp');

console_stamp(logger, {
    colors: {
        stamp: 'yellow',
        label: 'white',
        metadata: 'green'
    },
    stdout: output,
    stderr: errorOutput
});

logger.log( ' TEST LOG ' );
```

Comment: PERFECT!!!! ... so could I do something like `logger.log( ' TEST LOG ' ); console.log( ' TEST LOG ' );` if i wanted to log to both the console and file?

Comment: oh i just tried that and the console.log output doesn't have the timestamp :(

Comment: nevermind figured it out now that I have a better understanding on how this all works THANK YOU!!!